# How to perform background task without blocking the GUI but transfer back information to main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I would like to do the following:

- Have a button and a table on a GUI.
- When I press the button, a task is started
- This task is a while loop, giving me data on each iteration

How can I run this loop and obtain data from each iteration of it in the main GUI table, without blocking the GUI? This is important, because the while stop condition is again a button on the GUI.

I have tried using a `BackgroundWorker`, but I really cannot figure out how to send back data at every loop iteration (???) I can get back the result at the end, but that is not the target. If I launch the worker in a loop (but not have the loop in the worker), it does not work.

```
private void ContinuousCoordinateAquisition(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (continuousPositionAquisitionFlag == true)                       //  while the monitoring is not stopped, get positions
    {
        // get xyzwpr world coordinates
        robotCoordinatesXYZWPRworld XYZWPRworld = robi.getRobotPosition_xyzwpr_world();

        Do something........... retuns values I need in GUI

        // sleep for defined time
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //  wait 
    } 
}
```

the calling would be

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ContinuousCoordinateAquisition); 
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(ContinuousCoordinateAquisitionCompleted);
```

`continuousPositionAquisitionFlag` is set from a button (stop button).
`ContinuousCoordinateAquisitionCompleted` here is only done once unfortunately, not every iteration.

Comment: _Reactive Extensions_ are your friend

Comment: The Bgw has a ProgressChanged event, perfect for submitting data to the main thread.

Comment: But when you pause for 1000ms each loop you might be better of with a Timer.

Comment: could you give a short example? I tries sleep but it freezes the GUI so I never get to the stop button --> infinite loop.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You should use the background worker, but don't wait for the RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler, that happens when everything is done.

Instead, inside your loop periodically call the ReportProgress method on your background worker. That will trigger the ProgressChanged event that you can handle in your GUI thread.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, so I added:
 bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(ContinuousCoordinateAquisitionStep);

and 

private void ContinuousCoordinateAquisitionStep(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.???
        }

how can I get the values? e does not have the Result field here.....

Comment: Before starting the worker you need to set the WorkerReportsProgress property to True, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress(v=vs.110).aspx. At your "Do somthing" you should manually call the ReportProgress method with a parametar (thare is a userstate parameter, that is an object) that has the data you wish to transfer. That will trigger your ProgressChanged event. "e" will contain your object as well. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the BackgroundWorkClass WorkerReportsProgress property and handle the ProgressChanged event, as described by this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx